# Python class inheritance design: Pretend to look like a duck but don't quack

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiple-inheritance

I've searched for this for a few hours today but didn't get a recent and satisfactorily definitive answer.

Suppose we have two particular classes that have both overlapping method names and specific individual methods. Getting rid of the unnecessary parts let's work with the following classes.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a_arg1, a_arg2):
        self.a_arg1 = a_arg1
        self.a_arg2 = a_arg2

    @property
    def gimme_1(self):
        return self.a_arg1

    @property
    def gimme_2(self):
        return self.a_arg2

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'A'
```

and also

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, b_arg1, b_arg2, b_arg3):
        self.b_arg1 = b_arg1
        self.b_arg2 = b_arg2
        self.b_arg3 = b_arg3

    @property
    def give_1(self):
        return self.b_arg1

    @property
    def give_2(self):
        return self.b_arg2

    @property
    def give_3(self):
        return self.b_arg3

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'B'
```

My goal is to make a third class that can morph into one of these, namely, it will have all the methods that these two have and act as if it is one of them whichever is requested. That's the motivation for the title of the question.

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.some_list = some_list

    @property
    def gimme_1(self):
        return self.some_list[0]

    @property
    def gimme_2(self):
        return self.some_list[1]

    @property
    def give_1(self):
        return self.some_list[0] ** 2

    @property
    def give_2(self):
        return self.some_list[1] ** 2

    @property
    def give_3(self):
        return self.some_list[2]

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'C'
```

Concrete questions:

1. Do we have to initialize the parents for this particular instance? If yes how should the `super()` be used.
2. This would really help me getting away with `isinstance(x, A)` or `isinstance(x, B)` type of querying. Is there any *best practice* that discourages such usage? Notice that the Pythonic duck typing is really not so relevant for me in my case. There are a lot of branching necessarily happening for different computational algorithms. Hence I'm really using classes as data-bundling containers but not using them as state recorders. In other words, there is hardly ever change in their instance data. But their data is used in different branches depending on which class they are. Therefore getting the right kind of object is essential for me.

Comment: What do you mean *"morph into one of these"*? It *is* both of those. And yes, you should use `super` to ensure all of the relevant methods get called when subclassing. Or if you don't actually want it to be a subclass, why are you subclassing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you ask for any method that `A` or `B` has, from `C`, it would respond according just as it would have been `A` or `B`. Do I still need to call super even though I've overwrite all the methods?

Comment: Well duck typing means you don't care whether the object is/subclasses something, just that it has the relevant attributes. It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, but you probably don't need inheritance. Have you actually *tried* any of this? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have a look at question 2. What do you mean ? This is an actual problem I have simplified. I don't know what to look out for. That's why I am asking

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rewriting the methods, why not take advantage of the benefits of inheritance?  Let the parent `__init__`s take care of setting up instance values, and let them provide the method implementations.

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        A.__init__(self, arg1, arg2)
        B.__init__(self, arg1**2, arg2**2, arg3)

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'C'
```

Comment: The reason for the rewrite is that `C` doesn't really behave like `A` or `B` hence I'm trying to get a generic class that will still act like A or B but won't behave like them. So I will not be using any of `A` or `B` but if needed it will provide the necessary output in the format that `A` or `B` would have.

Comment: That's generally not a good sign for your design. You should take a step back and try to resolve this so that your types make sense. As a rule, inheritance should satisfy a "is a" relation ship. If I have a class `Car`, and a subclass `Ford(Car)`, that makes sense because every Ford is also a Car.  If you have a `Cat` class, and you want to write a `Dog` class, it doesn't make sense to use inheritance, even if the two would be largely similar. (You would instead make an `Animal` parent class). These are obviously simplistic examples, but I hope they help.

Comment: They are actually satisfying your car analogy. But imagine I've installed an electric engine to `C`. And in your analogy, I have two classes `Car` and `Truck`. And `C` becomes an electric powered Car or Truck. Their old gasoline based computations won't make sense anymore but I'd like to use Electric powered car or truck in any existing computations. However I have to tell my old codebase that this is still a vehicle and ask whichever you want from it.

Comment: There I would have a separate, abstract `Engine` class that can be subclassed to electric and gasoline (and hydrogen and so on) engines. Basically, the parts that interact with these changeable elements shouldn't care which implementation they're using.  If you aren't familiar with them, you might want to read about Java interfaces.  Python doesn't have a direct analogue, but it's a useful way to design your program.

Comment: Yes but there is no end to that granularity. As I mentioned, I'm not holding the state of the instances. That architecture is useful for its own use cases but not applicable everywhere. Using a class does neither immediately necessitates a modular design made up of different classes nor OOP has a single implementation paradigm. That's why I am asking for implicit problems. I am quite aware of Java mindset. And that's why I am using Python.

Comment: To answer your question then, the answer is no.  Using inheritance like this won't break anything, and (to my knowledge) none of the internal machinery of Python will be affected.